# In-page Linking with Shadow Root and Native Web Components

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, web-component, native-web-component

A very simple example of this problem is the [`<foot-note>`](https://github.com/FanaroEngineering/fanaro.io/blob/master/src/components/footnote.ts) custom web component I've created for my new website, [fanaro.io](https://fanaro.io).

Typically, what seems to work for in-page linking is creating and `id` for the specific element and then use an `<a>` with `href="#id_name"`. However this doesn't seem to work when the elements are inside the `shadowRoot`, the URL link still gets appended correctly, but nothing happens. Using `document.querySelector("#id_name");` also doesn't seem to work. You can click on any of the `<sup>` footnotes on [any of my articles](https://fanaro.io/articles/murugandi/murugandi#footnote-base-1) and then use inspection to check this out.

Is this a limitation of Web Components or am I missing something here? If I wish to do in-page linking, will I have to end up ditching Web Components? Or maybe add custom `onClick` methods?

> The problem has been solved and can be found before commit `4d2ef0d4fb5c8fe56c76d60eb7274c85bae81d94`. It's also linked in [this issue](https://github.com/FanaroEngineering/fanaro.io/issues/10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **not** a Web Component limitation, it is how shadowDOM works.

A *fragment identifier* works by ID references, so they only work in the 'main' DOM, not in shadowDOM (and not in IFRAMEs).

`document.querySelector( )` can't access those IDs in shadowDOM either, because the essence of shadowDOM is to isolate content.

So you either:

1. don't use shadowDOM, do you really need shadowDOM features?
   [image]
   That styling should be a global CSS setting, which is applied if you do **not** use shadowDOM
2. register a document click listener from every element with shadowDOM, which checks if a *fragment identifier* is in its shadowDOM scope
   because a Custom Element can access its host, something an IFRAME can not
   This Event model is the best for decoupled components **with** shadowDOM
3. write some more complex code that calls all `<foot-note>` **from the main DOM**

   ```
    [...document.querySelectorAll("foot-note")]
    .forEach( footnote => footnote.shadowRoot.getElementById(...) )
   ```

IMHO **none** of your Components in your site need shadowDOM;  it will make your design easier as you no longer have *shadowDOM scoped* CSS, everything will be global CSS

The W3C Web Components Standard has 3 **distinct** technologies

- Templates
- Custom Elements API
- shadowDOM

Each can be used **without** the other!

Comment: I agree with you. I didn't need the shadowDOM for what I was doing. But I thought it would work in my favor in the future due to its isolation – I just didn't know isolation meant some other limitations.

Comment: It is easier to add shadowDOM later than the other way around. Too many blogs dive straight in with all 3 Web Components technologies in one example.

Comment: This is probably the answer I was looking for, but I'll only be able to accept after I test it out, which I'm likely gonna do only late at night today. See you later!

Comment: Thanks for the very comprehensive answer, others with similar issues will surely find it helpful. It solved my problem and the changes are already online, I've also put a note on the question.